# How to get correct current page or category ID

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to get ID of current post, page, category or what ever queried by Wordpress.

I tried almost every function like:

```
    global $post;
    global $wp_query;
    $pid = $wp_query->post->ID;
    echo "ID = " . $pid . "<br />";
    echo "ID = " . get_the_ID() . "<br />";
    echo "ID = " . get_queried_object_id() . "<br />";
    echo "ID = " . $post->ID . "<br />";
```

I take a look in MySQL in wp_post and wp_postmeta and found that:
 - for Shop page post_id = 4
 - for Product post_id = 31
In wp_terms for Category - term_id = 15

I visit paths like:
 - shop
 - shop->category
 - shop->category->product
and echo the current post ID, it always is display 31
which in fact is product-id

How to get the Right ID of current end point of wordpress or woocommerce?

More information:

This code:

```
global $post, $page, $product;
echo "ID = " . get_queried_object_id();
```

almost work and show ID's as follow:

- shop                    ID:0 not correct
- shop->category          ID:15 correct
- shop->category->product ID:31 correct
- home page               ID:0 not correct
- post                    ID:0 not correct

I forget to say that this ID is retrieved in functions.php. 
In function that will get specific meta data for current node and echo-it in header hook.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
$queried_object = get_queried_object();

if ( $queried_object ) {
    $post_id = $queried_object->ID;
    echo $post_id;
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.